# Explicación programa cliente y servidor sockets

Tags: java, socket, redes

Tengo el programa Cliente:

```
class Cliente {
static final String HOST = "localhost";
static final int PUERTO=5000;
public Cliente( ) {
try{
Socket skCliente = new Socket( HOST , Puerto );
InputStream aux = skCliente.getInputStream();/* A partir de aquí no entiendo lo que hace */
DataInputStream flujo = new DataInputStream( aux );
System.out.println( flujo.readUTF() );
skCliente.close();  ... /* Hasta aquí */
} catch( Exception e ) {
System.out.println( e.getMessage() );

}
}
public static void main( String[] arg ) {
new Cliente();
}
}
```

Y Tengo el programa Servidor:

```
class Servidor {
static final int PUERTO=5000;
public Servidor( ) {
try {
ServerSocket skServidor = new ServerSocket(PUERTO); /* A partir de aquí no entiendo lo que hace */
System.out.println("Escucho el puerto " + PUERTO );
for ( int numCli = 0; numCli < 3; numCli++; ) {
Socket skCliente = skServidor.accept(); // Crea objeto
System.out.println("Sirvo al cliente " + numCli);
OutputStream aux = skCliente.getOutputStream();
DataOutputStream flujo= new DataOutputStream( aux );
flujo.writeUTF( "Hola cliente " + numCli );
skCliente.close();... /* Hasta aquí */
}
System.out.println("Demasiados clientes por hoy");
} catch( Exception e ) {
System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
}
}
public static void main( String[] arg ) {
new Servidor();/* No entiendo para que esta este main aqui? */
}
}
```

¿Me podrían explicar linea por linea lo que hace cada programa?, para comprender mejor el tema sobre los socket.

Comment: ¿Podrías reducir al mínimo el número de líneas que necesitas aclaración? Es mejor preguntar qué hace cada bloque de código o que te expliquen línea a línea un par de bloques de código que todo entero. También es importante saber si conoces el funcionamiento de cada clase usada o no para darte enlaces a sus definiciones. Si no es así tienes muchas posibilidades de que se te cierre la pregunta por ser demasiado amplia.

Comment: O mejor aún, marca lo que no entiendas o bloques. Por ejemplo: `/* No entiendo aquí el uso de la clase tal */` y bloques como `/* A partir de aquí no entiendo lo que hace */` ... `/* Hasta aquí */`.

Comment: Listo . Asi esta bien?

Comment: Hecho. Espero que te sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explicación de la clase cliente:

```
class Cliente {
    static final String HOST = "localhost";
    static final int PUERTO = 5000;
    public Cliente( ) {
        try {
            /* Creamos una instancia de Socket que se conectará al puerto TCP 5000 de "localhost" */
            Socket skCliente = new Socket( HOST , Puerto );
            /* Obtenemos corriente de entrada de datos para leer lo que nos manden */
            DataInputStream flujo = new DataInputStream( skCliente.getInputStream() );
            /* Leemos los datos que nos hayan enviado desde el servidor */
            System.out.println( flujo.readUTF() );
            /* Cerramos la conexión */
            skCliente.close();
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );

        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] arg ) {
        /* Al crear una instancia de esta misma clase se llamará al constructor, la función anterior */
        new Cliente();
    }
}
```

Explicación de la clase servidor:

```
class Servidor {
    static final int PUERTO = 5000;
    public Servidor( ) {
        try {
            /* Obtenemos una instancia de un servidor que escucha en el puerto 5000 conexiones TCP */
            ServerSocket skServidor = new ServerSocket(PUERTO);
            /* Escribo por pantalla el texto */
            System.out.println("Escucho el puerto " + PUERTO );
            /* Recibimos hasta un máximo de tres conexiones de clientes antes de finalizar */
            for ( int numCli = 0; numCli < 3; numCli++; ) {
                /* La aplicación se bloque hasta recibir una conexión de un cliente */
                Socket skCliente = skServidor.accept(); // Crea objeto
                /* Escribo por pantalla el texto */
                System.out.println("Sirvo al cliente " + numCli);
                /* Obtengo una corriente de datos de salida para escribir datos hacia el cliente */
                DataOutputStream flujo= new DataOutputStream( skCliente.getOutputStream() );
                /* Escribimos los datos para que los reciba el cliente */
                flujo.writeUTF( "Hola cliente " + numCli );
                /* Cerramos la conexión */
                skCliente.close();
            }
            System.out.println("Demasiados clientes por hoy");
        } catch( Exception e ) {
            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] arg ) {
        /* Al crear una instancia de esta misma clase se llamará al constructor, la función anterior */
        new Servidor();
    }
}
```

En ambos casos se hace uso de un envoltorio de las corrientes de datos `InputStream` y `OutputStream` usando [`DataInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html) y [`DataOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html) para escribir cadenas en UTF-8 usando [`readUTF`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUTF%28%29) y [`writeUTF`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html#writeUTF%28java.lang.String%29).